# Interfaces and @RequestBody

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm currently working on a project which allows users to book (via the web) the use of a chosen resource for a given period of time. In this program I am trying to keep with Spring's philosophy (and the general best practice) of programming to interfaces and as such I try to use interfaces anywhere where functionality is repeated among concrete classes.

One interface I have created is called a BookableResourceController which specifies the methods needed by a controller to handle the minimum required functionality for any type of resource to be booked. I also make use of a second interface, BookableResource, which identifies which objects model a resource that is allowed to be booked through the application.

The problem I am currently running into is that a few of the methods defined by BookableResourceController use the @RequestBody mapping to convert a JSON object into a method parameter, and since Jackson can only convert JSON into "SimpleType" objects, I receive an error if I specify the input parameter to be a BookableResource.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/delete.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
public ModelAndView processDeleteResource(
    @RequestBody BookableResource resource);
```

> Can not construct instance of
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.SimpleType,
>   problem: abstract types can only be
>   instantiated with additional type
>   information

From what I can tell this error means that I will need to define a specific implementation of BookableResource, meaning I will most likely need to exclude these methods from the interface even though any controller that is to be used for this purpose will require those methods.

What I am asking is if anyone knows a way to define an interface as the object that is expected from an `@RequestBody` mapping using JSON, or does anyone have any suggestions of how to structure my contoller interface in order to include these methods?

Cheers

Comment: please don't use `<code>` for code blocks. Select the code block and click the icon with the curly braces (or just indent with four spaces)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure it would work, but you can try to make it generic:

```
public interface BookableResourceController<R extends BookableResource> {
    @RequestMapping(value="/delete.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView processDeleteResource(@RequestBody R resource); 
}
```

Comment: That worked beautifully! I'm not too well versed in generics, so I never would have thought of this. Thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 2):

Additional way to go that can be used is to annotate interface with Jackson annotation:

```
@JsonDeserialize(as=BookableResourceImp.class)
```

(possibly using mix-in annotations if one does not want to add it directly in interface class)

**EDIT**: Another possibility is to use `SimpleModule` method `addAbstractTypeMapping()` to specify implementation type. This avoids linkage from interface to implementation, and may (or may not) be more convenient way to register this aspect.

Comment: This solution would couple the interface to the implementation, which seems like a bad practice?

Comment: @Chris if you have a choice between bad practice and no solution which one would you choose? Added another way to achieve this.

Comment: I have a case where the interface's default implementation is actually a factory, since I need the data to know which implementation to use, this solution helps a lot to achieve that.