# @RequestBody with generic

Tags: json, binding, jackson, spring-annotations

I have a necessity to deserialize a JSON message into a generic object/interface and not to a specific type.

I went throught this post [Interfaces and @RequestBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737579/interfaces-and-requestbody) and tried to implement the same.

But again it failed with the same error

```
Can not construct instance of XXXXX, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
```

When the control reaches the method, the object is constructed as a linked hash map.
What might have gone wrong? Am I approaching the solution rightly?

Comment: have you had any luck?

Comment: No. Not Yet. I've parked the experiment for now.